# Doctriny - Symfony Flush not adding to DataBase

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig, flush

The flush function does not add anything to the database even though it doesn't return any error.
Any idea of how can I solve that?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
#[Route("/messages")]
    public function create(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $signup, UserRepository $userRepository, MessageRepository $messageRepository): Response
    {
        $message = new Message();
        $userRepository = $signup->getRepository(User::class);
        $formdico = [];
        foreach ($userRepository->findAll() as $user) {
            $userform = $this->createForm(MessageType::class, $message);
            $formdico[$user->getId()] = $userform;
        }

        foreach ($formdico as $form) {
            
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $newMessage = new Message();
                $newMessage->setSender($userRepository->findOneById($form->getData()->getSender()));
                $newMessage->setReceiver($userRepository->findOneById($form->getData()->getSender()));
                $newMessage->setContent($form->getData()->getContent());
                $newMessage->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
                
                $em = $signup->getManager();
                $em->persist($newMessage);
                $em->flush($newMessage);
            }   
        }
        foreach ($userRepository->findAll() as $user) {
            $userform = $this->createForm(MessageType::class, $message);
            $formdico[$user->getId()] = $userform->createView();
        }
        return $this->render('message/readAllUser.html.twig', ['users' => $userRepository->findAll(), "formdico" => $formdico, 'messages' => $messageRepository->findAll()]);
    }
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity()]
class Message
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "AUTO")]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "App\Entity\User", inversedBy: "sendedMessages")]
    private $sender;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "App\Entity\User", inversedBy: "receivedMessages")]
    private $receiver;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "text")]
    private string $content;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "date")]
    private \DateTime $createdAt;


    /**
     * Get the value of id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of sender
     */
    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of sender
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setSender($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of receiver
     */
    public function getReceiver()
    {
        return $this->receiver;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of receiver
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setReceiver($receiver)
    {
        $this->receiver = $receiver;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of content
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of content
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of createdAt
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of createdAt
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Message;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;

class MessageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sender', IntegerType::class, [])
            ->add('content', TextType::class, ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Message Content']])
            ->add('receiver', IntegerType::class, []);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Message::class,]);
    }
}
```

I tried removing the persist, dumped a lot of things to try understanding the problem but I can't get to solve this...
And the form is valid

Comment: can you add the config of the involved entities?

Comment: Double-check if your form is valid.

Comment: You should set the receiver as the current user iterater by foreach loop, either you can save the user in variable, check this code: https://pastebin.com/VanLvqt6